# How can I put functions in other cs file?

Tags: c#, c++

In C/C++, I can create a file and put all functions in this file.

**lib.h**

```
void plus(int i, int j);
```

**lib.cpp**

```
#include "lib.h"

void plus(int i, int j)
{
    printf("%d\n", i+j);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "lib.h"
main()
{
    plus(1, 2);
}
```

But in C#, How can I put functions in other `cs` file and include it in `main.cs`?

Comment: Why do you want to do like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you shouldn't really be doing this. In the C/C++ world this is done because you can't use functions declared later on in the program.

Also header files serve as an interface to shared libraries on your OS or from some vendor.

So what @Tigran says is the *equivalent* of the same principal in C#. You declare an iterface.

If you really wanted to do what you're asking in the **literal sense** you could use **partial functions**. I'm putting it here for anyone curious. The purpose this was designed for is different from C/C++ so you will need to evaluate whether you really want to do this, I think you don't.

You can do this, [see msdn for more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6b0scde8.aspx):

```
namespace PM
{
    partial class A
    {
        partial void OnSomethingHappened(string s);
    }

    // This part can be in a separate file. 
    partial class A
    {
        // Comment out this method and the program 
        // will still compile. 
        partial void OnSomethingHappened(String s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something happened: {0}", s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the only answer that actually addressed what the OP wanted, even if it's not a common thing in C#.

Comment: @tenpn What someone want and what someone actually need are often different. OP did not explain why he wants it, so we can assume that he just wants it because that is how it was done in C/C++. All other answers are more appropriate than this one. But I learned something new from this one, so I'm not complaining.

Comment: @Dialecticus you can assume that, but you might be wrong! Best to do exactly what gideon has done here - "that's not best practice, but here's how..." Informative in both how it should be done, and the esoteric ways to stretch the language.

Comment: @tenpn too much information can mess with our reasoning. This is something that I can't explain to some people, as they believe that there is no such thing as too much information.

Answer (score 1):

You don't do it like that in C#.

In C#, firstly note that ALL functions (called methods in C#) must be in a class. You can't have them floating around naked like in C++.

Secondly, to access a C# class that is defined in another ".cs" file:

- If the class is defined in a different assembly (i.e. it's in a different DLL) then you must add to your project a reference to that assembly.
- Then if the namespace that contains that class is the same as the namespace for the class that needs to use the method, you don't need to do anything more.
- Otherwise, at the top of the source code file you have to put a [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) that specifies the namespace that contains the class you need. Alternatively, you can specify the full namespace in the method call itself.

Note that to use the method, you will either have to instantiate an instance of the containing class, or that method must be static and you access it using `ClassName.MethodName()` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like follow the same concerns like in `C++` (for some reason) in `C#` to achieve this is declare (say) an `interface` in one file and it's implementation in another, but basically in your case I would suppose you do not need that, you basically need to:

- declare a class in one file
- instantiate in `main.cs` file
- use it

There are a lot of other different aspects of `C#` that may look familiar to you like `C++` developer, so I would suggest to learn it a little bit.

Comment: @Ritesh:yeah, thanks  :) recently I'm for 80% on web development, so this is a result :)